# Nexus Jenkins plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, nexus

I've been trying to configure the **Nexus Jenkins** plugin for about a week now. Only to find out that the plugin didn't work with our Nexus 3.x oss.

Since then I have downgraded our nexus and have configured everything to work. Except, when I try to add the Maven artifact file path to the *jenkins.war* file I get an error with the following message:

```
Uploading Maven asset with groupId: com.riddlesvillage artifactId: core 
version: Version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT To repository: releases
Upload of /usr/share/jenkins/ failed
Failing build due to failure to upload file to Nexus Repository Manager 

Publisher
FATAL: Upload of /usr/share/jenkins/ failed
    ...

Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to copy /usr/share/jenkins to 
/tmp/jenkins6954159502505207420tmp `$`
```

Tho, when I move the file path and leave it empty it builds, but it still doesn't upload anything to nexus.

Answer (score 0):

If you did follow "[How do I configure the Nexus Jenkins Plugin](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/227256688-How-do-I-configure-the-Nexus-Jenkins-Plugin) " and it is still not working, the only alternative is to do the deployment to Nexus yourself with a mvn command.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=<group-id> \
  -DartifactId=<artifact-id> \
  -Dversion=<version> \
  -Dpackaging=<type-of-packaging> \
  -Dfile=<path-to-file> \
  -DrepositoryId=<id-to-map-on-server-section-of-settings.xml> \
  -Durl=<url-of-the-repository-to-deploy>
```

See "[Guide to deploying 3rd party JARs to remote repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html)": that is what I have been using,... and it works both with Nexus 2.x and Nexus 3.x

Comment: How to handle the Jenkins-to-Nexus authentication in this case?

Comment: @KaliyugAntagonist The authentication would be stored in the `~/.m2/settings.xml` used by the account running the job on the Jenkins agent.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the official documentation for the same? I am new to jenkins and unaware of the 'agent', 'slave' components.

Comment: @KaliyugAntagonist links of interest: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Maven+Plugin https://stackoverflow.com/q/7807171/6309, https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin, https://stackoverflow.com/a/43796714/6309